# New DIY project try to understand MPPT

Tags: solar-cell, mppt, panel

I got used battery MODULE with the next specs

"40V 18.4AH 736WH build of ninety six A123-26650 LITHIUM LIFEPO4 cell "

Cell specs:

- Nominal Capacity: 2300mAh
- Voltage(nominal,V): 3.3V
- Internal impedance(1kHz AC typical,mΩ): 6
- HPPC 10 Sec Discharge Pulse Power 50% SOC: 200W
- Recommended standard charge method: 1C to 3.6V CCCV, 45 min
- Recommended fast charge Method to 80% SOC: 4C to 3.6V CC,12 min
- Maximum continuous discharge(A): 70
- Maximum Pulse discharge(10 seconds,A) 120
- Cycle life at 10C discharge, 100% DOD: Over 1,000 cycles

---

I plan to get either:

1. Solar panel with 18v and 400 watt
2. Wind turbine 24v and 600 watt

There is a big different between VDC and the Battery voltage. 
Can MPPT solve this issue and if the answer is yes what will be the MPPT sepcs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because move to DIY.SE

Comment: how is this any way about home improvement...

Comment: @laptop2d could you please send me the link of DIY.SE

Comment: @Passerby This is small scale one and I hope to upgrade it later. just testing the water

Comment: 8P12S battery sounds pretty serious. Is there a datasheet to go with this? Generally, MPPT controllers can rise the output voltage above panel output. MPPT _charger_ controllers can do that and also provide required CCCV profile. However you did not specify whether you want to use separate charger, power the load simultaneously with charging and what research you did so far. In short - not nearly enough to base an answer on.

Comment: @Maple I'm new and don't have all the info. the battery info is https://www.ebay.com/itm/173304996422
About the separate charger, yes I'll use charger for each module in other words I'll try anything to make it work, and this is the point

Comment: MPPT is simply an approach to getting the maximum power out of your solar panel or wind turbine.  MPPT does nothing to increase the voltage - which is what you need to do to charge the battery.  You need a charge controller that can step up the voltage.

Comment: @SimonB Every MPPT controller (including non-charging) has DC-DC converter, so it can buck or boost or both, depending on the implementation. For example here is a random controller chip I googled: [SPV1040](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spv1040.pdf). Connected in boost schematics it delivers 5V from as low as 0.3V input. You need a charge controller if you want your MPPT to control battery charging as well, which is more efficient than using external charger.